# charge monthly subscription not done through iOS App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I know that Apple has a great way to add monthly subscription IAP's to your app in the App Store, but I have a client who would prefer to use a different service to charge for this subscription that could tie in to their website. Does anyone know if Apple allows you to charge a monthly subscription inside your app via an online credit card processor (like Stripe or Chargify) rather than being required to do so through the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that Apple would let you do this as you are then circumventing the IAP program. You could possibly redirect the user out of the app like Spotify does, but this could still get the app rejected - a small part of the review process depends on which reviewer you get!

Reference in the app store guidelines:

**11.2** ([source](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies))

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Comment: Yeah that is the question I have is how do some apps like Spotify get to go around this guideleline (I would like to think that Apple would allow smaller companies to do the same if they let one of the big apps do so, but I think you're right that it all depends on who reviews your project)

Comment: I have a feeling that Apple might let the big/popular apps get away with it. Though there's nothing against you trying it with your app - redirecting the user to a web site. Match what Spotify does, if the app gets rejected, appeal it, giving examples of a few apps that do exactly the same as your app does.